# How do you test if two discrete ECDFs are drawn from the same population?

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, distance, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

### Background

I have two Empirical Cumulative Distribution Functions (ECDFs) based on two samples of very different sizes.

##### Sample 1:

1020 data points, Power-Law-like distribution, discrete data in the natural numbers:

[image]

##### Sample 2:

908,768 data points, Power-law-like distribution, discrete data in the natural numbers:

[image]

Visual inspection shows they have very different percentiles. Practically all the distribution in Sample 2 is in the 1st percentile. Whereas Sample 1 has closer to 80%.

### Question

I can see visually they're different, but what can I do to prove it statistically?

Comment: "Significantly different" is too vague to lead to anything useful.  Please state *which properties* of these distributions (such as means, medians, variances, specific percentiles, whatever) are of interest: *that* can be tested.

Comment: @whuber, I've updated the question. Hopefully, the visualisations will make what I'm trying to do clearer. I think percentiles are the easiest to compare, but if you think there's something better, I'd like to hear that too.

Comment: *All* data distributions differ, so perhaps the better question is not proving that, but characterizing *how* they differ.  A good place to start that investigation is with a probability plot.  You can demonstrate the difference is unlikely to be due to random sampling simply by bootstrapping any useful measure of distance.  The KS distance ought to work well for your situation.

Comment: Thank you! I have come across DTS, does that work here too?

Comment: What does DTS stand for in this context?

Comment: I'm not sure where the acronym comes from, but it's a two sample test statistic based on anderson darling, and wass distance: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11135-023-01687-8#:~:text=The%20DTS%20test%20identifies%20distributional,formulas%20with%20asymptotic%20ASR%20characteristics.

Comment: @Glen_b I believe this is the original paper for DTS: https://codowd.com/public/DTS.pdf

Comment: Thanks very much for the link, that looks interesting. Unless I missed it, Dowd never seems to mention what DTS stands for, sadly. I presume he thinks it's obvious; maybe I'll figure it out on a closer read.

Comment: @Glen_b You're welcome, I've seen it talked about on CV elsewhere as the new best way to characterise differences, but still haven't seen what the Acronym stands for.

Comment: There can be no single best way unless we define carefully what we specifically want to be best at, (and perhaps not even then). e.g. if you're trying to have good power to detect that two distributions differ, Anderson-Darling doesn't always beat Kolmogorov-Smirnov at that task, even though it's often better for many interesting alternatives.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you! Always good to be reminded of this. Are there books that discuss why statistics rarely has one best to complete a task and how to properly set up the parameters of your problems so you can narrow down your options?

Comment: There's two issues. One is when I was discussing that what's "best" depends on what you're optimizing, which is not a statistical issue -- that's general to any attempt to optimize. You can't get to best unless you know what you're aiming for (otherwise you end up solving the wrong problem). The second is that there may be no optimum (e.g. you can specify that "best" means "has the highest power to detect differences" but no uniformly most powerful test exists when you have omnibus alternatives. Indeed, that's generally the case even with two-sided alternatives and a single parameter)